# Is there any way to use css class in foreignObject of svg which be drawn into canvas?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there any way to make my html use class in foreignObject of svg? For now, it can just use style attribute in every tag but that's too bad :(

I look up some converters which convert class in html to inline style, but both of them have all kinds of problems.

So is there any better solution?

----------------------------------edit-----------------------------

Sorry, I miss some words, I want to insert the svg into canvas(by converting it to Blob and then call `ctx.drawImage`)

Comment: Being a global attribute, `class` [can be used](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement) on virtually any HTML tag, including SVG's `<foreignObject>`.

Comment: Sorry, update the question

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a `style` tag inside that svg tag. Any style given in that `style` tag will be available inside that foreignObject. For Example,

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .container {
      color: white;
      font: 18px serif;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>

  <polygon points="5,5 195,10 185,185 10,195" />

  <!-- Common use case: embed HTML text into SVG -->
  <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">
    <!--
      In the context of SVG embedded in an HTML document, the XHTML
      namespace could be omitted, but it is mandatory in the
      context of an SVG document
    -->
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum,
      porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam
      erat volutpat.
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

source [MDN Web Docs - foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)